# Python Redis hmset with large dataset does not insert all objects

Tags: python, redis

I have about 3.3M objects that I would like to insert into a Redis hash via something like the following pseudocode:

```
import redis
import json

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)    
try:
  for record in records:
    serialized_record = { 'record' : json.dumps(record) }
    r.hmset(record['name'], serialized_record)
catch redis.exceptions.RedisError as e:
  ...
catch redis.exceptions.DataError as e:
  ...
```

I'm leaving out a fair amount of detail here, but this is the gist of what I'm doing.

In this case, the `record['name']` key and its value pairing are just strings taken from each of the 3.3M lines in a ~1.5GB text file.

**The problem**

My problem is that when I run this import in one pass, I get no exceptions, but some objects towards the end of the import — a fair number, in fact — do not get put into the database.

In other words, when I open `redis-cli` to test with `hmget` for various known `record['name']` names, some records will be returned correctly, and some records will return `(nil)`, which is incorrect.

Something failed with `hmset` that causes these `(nil)` records, but no exceptions are thrown during the import stage. (At least, no exceptions get thrown that trigger the `try..catch` block.)

**What I've tried**

If I break up my set into smaller imports, say 100k objects per import, then the Python script works.

If I have the `redis-cli` open in another terminal during an import, and if I run `LASTSAVE` to track saves, it appears that saves to the Redis database are performed every minute or so, during import.

**Questions**

What can I do to make Redis `hmset` work robustly under Python for a full import, or how do I debug this problem, if the cause is elsewhere?

Do I need to periodically save the database as I insert hash entries via Python, (every N records, for instance)?

Is a minimum amount of memory required for an import of a large dataset? This host has 2GB of memory, and I have allocated 1GB of it to the Redis server. Is this enough when importing? The records are read in, parsed, and `hmset` one record at a time.

**What I'm running**

I'm using: Redis server `5.0.3`, and Python `3.6.7` on Ubuntu 18, which is running the `redis-3.2.0` API library.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you try running an `hmget` assertion after each insert, for the entire batch?  Maybe you can pinpoint where the problem begins.  Also, try to estimate how much memory your 3.3M objects would require.

Comment: Hmm. This `hmget` assert test fails if I put it immediately after the insertion with `hmset`. Is `hmset` asynchronous? I can't seem to find in Python documentation for `hmset` whether or not the `hmset` occurs synchronously.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess my comment just opened some things to investigate.